# How to calculate percentage in sql in same table

Tags: sql

I have one table named, "employee" with the fields: name, age, id and salary.  I want to calculate the percentage of each employee's salary from total of the salary field.

Actual Table Data is,

```
   ----------------------------------
    name     age country id salary 
  -----------------------------------
    prashant 27  india   1  40000 
    aryan    28  nepal   2  45000 
    Reeta    29  india   12 46000 
    Navin    25  India   8  45000 
    Praveen  18  uk      7  40000 
    karan    24  us      3  42000 
    Varun    27  uk      4  50000 
    Ashish   19  us      5  51000 
    Neha     18  uk      6  32000 
    Rajesh   30  uk     13  47000 
    Rahman   32  us     14  48000
   ----------------------------------
```

Expected Result is,

```
--------------------------------------------
name     age   country id  salary  percent 
--------------------------------------------
prashant 27    india    1  40000    8% 
aryan    28    nepal    2  45000    9% 
Reeta    29    india   12  46000    9% 
Navin    25    India    8  45000    9% 
Praveen  18    uk       7  40000    8% 
karan    24    us       3  42000    9% 
Varun    27    uk       4  50000    10% 
Ashish   19    us       5  51000    10% 
Neha     18    uk       6  32000    7% 
Rajesh   30    uk      13  47000    10% 
Rahman   32    us      14  48000    10% 
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What is the datatype of your salary column?

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: int is data type of salary column

Comment: name varchar(50) Checked
age int Checked
country varchar(100) Checked
id int Checked
salary int Checked
  Unchecked

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Total INT

SELECT @Total = SUM(Salary) AS [TotalSalaries]
FROM Employee 

SELECT Name, Age, Salary, (Salary / @Total) * 100 AS [PctOfTotalSalaries]
FROM Employee
```

Comment: not working showing error    
select sum(salary) as (totalsalaryies), (salary / sum (salary))* 100 as (total) from people

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: what do mean by last comment and 2nd query also not working

Comment: Then your doing something wrong.   My query is just an example.. replace your table name, don't execute using my exact SQL..

Comment: i'm using my column and table name

Comment: name age country id salary
prashant 27 india 1 40000
aryan 28 nepal 2 45000
Reeta 29 india 12 46000
Navin 25 India 8 45000
Praveen 18 uk 7 40000
karan 24 us 3 42000
Varun 27 uk 4 50000
Ashish 19 us 5 51000
Neha 18 uk 6 32000
Rajesh 30 uk 13 47000
Rahman 32 us 14 48000 this my table data

Comment: name age country id salary percent
prashant 27 india 1 40000 8%
aryan 28 nepal 2 45000 9%
Reeta 29 india 12 46000 9%
Navin 25 India 8 45000 9%
Praveen 18 uk 7 40000 8%
karan 24 us 3 42000 9%
Varun 27 uk 4 50000 10%
Ashish 19 us 5 51000 10%
Neha 18 uk 6 32000 7%
Rajesh 30 uk 13 47000 10%
Rahman 32 us 14 48000 10%
 now i want to show data like that

Answer (score 1):

If you RDBMS supports windows functions, you can proceed as follows:

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    age, 
    id,
    salary, 
    100.00 * salary / (SUM(salary) OVER()) percent_salary
FROM mytable
```

`SUM(salary) OVER()` does a window sum; since the `OVER()` clause is empty, the window includes the whole table, and this returns the total of all salaries in the column.

Comment: its help full if you explain why you used over

Comment: @newleaner: welcome. I added a few explanation on the use of the window function.

Comment: @newleaner if it is working as you expected then accept this answer.